# Performing raster calculation in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have a raster layer with values between 0 and 10.

My second layer consists of 0's and 1's.

What I need is my first layer, but with 0's or NoData values where my second layer has 1's?

Comment: Have a look at the con tool in spatial analyst toolbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) tool with the following parameters (put the full path to the first, second and output rasters, not like I did here):

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help :)